# csv file to phpmyadmin import error

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, excel-2010

here is the pattern of my csv file

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |  
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |   
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   col1    |   col2   |           |   col4   |            |  
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

i have something like this, empty columns on the table in .csv file in excel 2010.
empty column has default data set in phpmyadmin.
while importing it's throwing **Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.**

how can i solve this?

thanks in advance.!

**Edit:**

here is the sample of my csv file

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   3.5 Inches   |      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   3.5 Inches   |      |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |   4.5 Inches   |      |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   9    |   6   |           |   Yes, Capacitive   |    4 Inches    |      | 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

first row ends at eight line and u can see some of the data cells dont have quotes, why it's not including by default??

Comment: What does the raw csv data look like where there's no data?

Comment: match the field delimiters of your csv file with the phpmyadmin delimiters

Comment: @DJDavid98 few columns are completely numeric, few are alpha-numeric and remaining are alphabetic.

Comment: copy few lines from real csv, not excel. and check the delimiter. maybe try to make a php function with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE if you want :)

Comment: @enigmaticus delimiter is comma as i opened with notepad. but i have data which do have comma and in notepad does it affect??, i can see few cells doesnt have quotes enclosed with and escaped with and few cells have.

Comment: @PravinS i have matched but still it gives the same.

Comment: post some csv sample data

Comment: @PravinS i have edited with sample data.

Comment: Your sample data seems to have a lot more than the six fields your table structure seems to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that i did is

1. Imported the file.
2. selected the Format to **CSV using load data**
3. Replaced **Columns separated with: to comma(,)**
4. then press GO.

DONE